# show only some text lines and hide all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want only show only this red mark line.

I think you have any other think like add in code only show
"6 OVR CSK", "6 OVR PBKS", 20 OVR CSK, 20 OVR PBKS.

I mean if this possible you add in you code to if this show only ?

```
setInterval(() => {
      const els = document.querySelectorAll(".tripple");
      if (els) {
        [].forEach.call(els, (div) => {
          const el = div.querySelector('.name');
          if (!(/\d+\sove?r/ig.test(el.textContent))) {
            div.setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 0.5') // opacity el
            div.style.display = 'none' // hide el
          }
        });
      }
      1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a trim and a start `^` like this :

```
 if (!(/^\d+\sove?r/ig.test(el.textContent.trim()))) {`
```

assuming your string is `6 OVR LSG`

Simpler example:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    const els = document.querySelectorAll(".fancy-tripple");
    if (els) {
      els.forEach(div => {
        const el = div.querySelector('.country-name a');
        div.hidden = !/^\d+\sove?r/ig.test(el.textContent.trim());
      });
    }
  },
  1000)
```

```html
<div>43 100</div>
<div>45 100</div>
<div>6 OVR LSG</div>
<br/>
<div>43 100</div>
<div>45 100</div>
<div class="fancy-tripple"><span class="country-name"><a>6 OVR CSK 100</a></span></div>
<br/>
<div>154 100</div>
<div>156 100</div>
<div class="fancy-tripple"><span class="country-name"><a>1.6 OVR LSG</a></span></div>
<br/>
<div>154 100</div>
<div>156 100</div>
<div class="fancy-tripple"><span class="country-name"><a>20 OVR LSG</a></span></div>
<br/>
<div>160 100</div>
<div>162 100</div>
<div class="fancy-tripple"><span class="country-name"><a>20 OVR CSK</a></span></div>
<br/>
<div>2 100</div>
<div>3 100</div>
<div class="fancy-tripple"><span class="country-name"><a>31ST INN O TO 10 OVERS</a></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for help me. this is working for me, now i need to help with hide

Comment: The code will hide what you asked. Including the 1.6